# Appcelerator stop children firing parents event

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, stoppropagation, event-propagation

I have a parent View with an click event and an attribute. within this i have 5 other elements. The issue is if i click on one of those elements it picks up the parents event listener and the code which is called checks to see if the clicked element has a specific data attribute.

is there any way to only apply the click event to the parent and not the children?

currently i am checking if the e.source has the attribute and if not checking the parent but it feels wrong.

Example code:

```html
<View onClick='foo' target='someId'>
    <imageView/>
    <imageView/>
    <imageView/>
</View>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set `touchEnabled : false` on your `ImageView`

Answer (score 2):

Setting `bubbleParent: false` will work for you, and you can keep `touchEnabled: true` just in case you still need touch events on `ImageView`.